# Fedora Legacy Releases; Cannot Locate on Site

Tags: fedora, legacy, fedora-23

I am looking for a Fedora 23 distribution. Currently Fedora is on version 27 as suggested by its homepage.

https://getfedora.org/

I cannot seem to find any legacy releases on the Fedora Project website. Does Fedora not keep their legacy releases?

Answer (score 1):

We do! You can find them on our archive server at

http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/